# Unable to login into Salesforce1 app from iPhone6. What might be the issue?

Tags: salesforce1-app

One of the users from my client side was using Salesforce1 app from his iOS device but now suddenly he is not able to do so. He saying that each time he enters the Username+Password , he is again prompted to do so. We had raised a Case with Salesforce and were informed that his login request are not reaching Salesforce servers. He has tried re-installation of APP , Reset, Power OFF-ON. but all in vain.

We had tried contacting our client helpdesk too to check that something from there servers should not restrict his request to go. But they also told that nothing is happening from there end.

Does anybody know what might be other reasons for the same ? And how to resolve the issue ?

Comment: What is the error message he's getting? timeout? wrong credentials? something else?

Comment: He just says that he is again prompted to enter Username & Password.

Comment: Then perhaps the answer below by @Arun SFDC is correct? Enable cookies?

Comment: Hmm....I have asked the user to check the same. Awaiting for his response now.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce.com presents a login error message when attempting to login through the iPhone's Safari web browser.

Solution: Enable cookies for Safari.

> Steps: Close any Salesforce.com web pages in Safari. Go to the
>   'Settings' app. Scroll down and tap on 'Safari'. Under the Privacy
>   header, tap on 'Accept Cookies'. Change the selection to 'Always'.
>   Login to Salesforce.com through Safari.
>
> NOTE: You may need to re-launch Safari if you still can not login.
>   Double tap the 'Home' button. Tap and hold on the 'Safari' app. Tap on
>   the 'stop' icon. Tap on the screen to close the task manager. Open
>   Safari.